# How to install JDK and JRE

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to run an application (monitor.exe) for monitoring things going on with my device when running a test program, but I am getting the following error message:

```
A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Monitor. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
C:\Users\Datu1\AppData\Local\ANdroid\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH
```

Can I install via Android Studio or should I go to the Oracle website? Is it a single installation package for both the JRE and JDK? Also I have tried running command line commands to see if the JDK is installed as well as searching folders and it is not installed.

Comment: Where are you trying to run this `mointor.exe` file? Are you running it on an Android device or on a desktop or laptop? If the later, then just install the JRE or JDK from the Oracle website. Note that the JDK contains the JRE, but not the other way around.

Comment: @technoman23 Seems like you should only need to go to the Oracle website and download & install the JRE for your machine, JDK shouldn't be needed for only running and testing.

Answer (score 0):

As @davedwards has said above, you would need to download and install the JRE from the Oracle website. If you still run into problems once installed or you have already installed the JRE you may need to check your PATH system variable.
The help section on the Oracle website [Here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
Will take you through this process.